# Android: Storage Options

Tags: java, android, local-storage, sharedpreferences

I am creating an application that allows the user to store information about food recipes that they can share on social media. I have an activity that allows the user to upload an image, write ingredients and directions for the recipe. In the past I have worked with shared preferences for saving user information, however, I know that the information stored is unordered. So I want to know what type of storage I should use to achieve this outcome....

My activity that saves user data:

[image]

From this I want to load the information into a previous activities list view that will have this type of list element layout:
[image]

From this what type of storage approach should I take? if I use shared preferences can I just place the parts I need into the elements of the list manually, for example, extracting the image saved from the user and placing that inside the image section of the listviews? or will the limitations of shared get in the way and maybe use internal storage? what would be the best approach?

Comment: Do you want to save everything locally?

Comment: I don't mind doing it locally or externally, SQL, Internal or shared preferences, but from my question, I just want to know the easiest method to get this result. I would prefer to use shared if I can achieve this result as I have used them before and the key-values makes it less complicated.

Comment: Hi, If you want to use shared preference then store data as json, in your shared preference which you can get by same as key value using Json object,

Comment: I would not recommend SharedPreferences. Shared Preferences is not suited when you have lots of data. If you want to store it locally, SQLite is your best bet. If possible try to save the data in the server, and fetch them when needed!

Comment: Would you say I am saving lots of data? just an image and some text?

Comment: use SQLite as the database to store info

Comment: @GeorgeBrooks Since you are list a ListView, I assumed you will be saving data for every row. Even with one row only, I recommend you to use SQlite.

Comment: use FIREBASE database. it's provided by google. It has key-value pair structure data

Answer (score 0):

Form a structured JSON object out of your data and you can use [REALM](https://realm.io/). It is a new and easy alternative to SQLite. 
It is very fast, easy to learn and integrate in your app.
Also, it is scalable means if you decide that you will be taking the same data to your backend then it will be easy for you to handle large amount of data.